# Divs overlapping but only in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html

I have been creating a website and the result has been fine in Chrome, IE9, Opera and Safari, BUT in Firefox some of the divs seem to overlap.

Here are some screenshots of a very cutdown version of the site in Chrome and Firefox, respectively:

http://i.imgur.com/VrYoB93.png?1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/57zaU.png

I would be grateful if you could take a look and tell me what I have done wrong. The full source so far is here:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <a href=""><img src="../Images/test.png"/></a>
        <a href=""><img src="../Images/Twitter1.png" class="headerlink"/></a>
        <a href=""><img src="../Images/YouTube2.png" class="headerlink"/></a>
        <a href=""><img src="../Images/Ask.fm.png" class="headerlink"/></a>
    </div>
    <div> <!-- Links -->
        <table align="center" width="900" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <td align="center" class="linkbarselected">Example link</td>
            <td align="center" class="linkbar"><a href="">Example link</a></td>
            <td align="center" class="linkbar"><a href="">Example link</a></td>
            <td align="center" class="linkbar"><a href="">Example link</a></td>
            <td align="center" class="linkbar"><a href="">Example link</a></td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        Example text in sidebar.
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <span style="font-size:2em; color:red;">Good day!</span><p>
            Example text blah blah blah<p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
}
.container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    background: transparent;
    float: left;
}
.linkbar {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 15px;
}
.main {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.content {
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 230px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.headerlink {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: can you put this in a jsFiddle for us?

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/) … and don't use [layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pJZ6F/

Comment: I did validate it - it was fine apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the float bug. 
Look at what I did.

jsfiddle.net/pJZ6F/1

Comment: Oh yeah, I noticed that but it doesn't seem to be the problem. Thanks, though.

Comment: Try putting "<div style="clear:both"></div>" at the end of your wrapper div's. It might be the float bug.

Comment: Cheers - the links still seem to be floating but I can probably fix that.

Comment: Why not explain what you did in the answer instead of readers having to compare the code diff in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Give header class a property

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Hope it helps!!